# Find cell address for MAX+IF function based on category

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a large set of data, which has been divided into 9 categories using numbers 1-9. The data is not sorted by category, but the categories are defined in a column as data. Using MAX+IF, I have a function that finds the max value for a specific parameter, for each category 1-9. Now, I want to get data from the same row that the max value came from.

I have tried using the ADDRESS+MATCH function, but the problem is that this sometimes returns a cell address that corresponds to a different category 1-9. This is because there are often repeats in the data set. However, it's unimportant if there are repeats in the same category, so only 1 row of data needs to be found. I have tried using the IF function before the ADDRESS+MATCH function, but it did not seem to filter the results.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the data out you probably want to use index,match and not address match.

Assume your categories are in column A, values in column B (data from row 1 through 15)

Max value entered with ctrl+shift+enter

```
=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$15=F2,$B$1:$B$15,0))
```

To grab the value in column C entered with ctrl+shift+enter

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$15,MATCH(G2,IF($A$1:$A$15=F2,$B$1:$B$15,-99),0))
```

F2 is the catagory, G2 is where the max of that category is stored.